# jQuery div not hiding on page reload

Tags: jquery, cookies

How could I get the `.policyDiv` to show when the page is loaded but hide on reload until the cookies are cleared?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!$.cookie("policy"))
    {
        $.cookie("policy", "DFG Policy");
        $(".policyDiv").show()
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!$.cookie("policy"))
    {
        $.cookie("policy", "DFG Policy");
        $(".policyDiv").show()
    }else{
        $(".policyDiv").hide()
    }
})
</script>
```